# Import local package that's already in public repo

Tags: go

I am working on building a web framework in Go. I have the code locally and would like to use that repo in another module to test that everything works without having to create tags and/or push things to remote repos. I have followed the official docs on how to do this, as well as a number of posts elsewhere. However nothing seems to work. What am I doing incorrectly?

Package live here locally:

```
../goworkspace/src/github.com/garrettlove8/goserve
```

Import from other module:

```
...
import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/garrettlove8/goserve" // I have tried "goserve" and "../goserve"
)
...
```

go.mod:

```
...
require github.com/garrettlove8/goserve v0.1.17
```

No matter what I do it doesn't seem to work as desired

**Update**

Code and error combos:

```
// main.go
import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"

    "goserve"
)
```

Run `go mod tidy`

```
// go.mod becomes
require github.com/garrettlove8/goserve v0.1.17 // indirect
```

Error:

```
goserve: package goserve is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/goserve)
```

Manually changing go mod to this (which I don't to have to do):

```
require github.com/garrettlove8/goserve
```

Run `go mod tidy`

Error:

```
usage: require module/path v1.2.3
```

Comment: can you please share the error logs

Comment: Execute `go get -u github.com/garrettlove8/goserve` from within your module

Comment: I didn't understand if you want the remote version or the local version of that package, if you want the local version, you can do that with [mod replace](https://thewebivore.com/using-replace-in-go-mod-to-point-to-your-local-module/)

Comment: @neo73 See updates

Comment: @Z.Kosanovic I wanted local, sorry for the confusion. I'll give that a try now.

Comment: @Z.Kosanovic Doesn't seem to work

Comment: Did you run `go get -u github.com/garrettlove8/goserve`?

Comment: @Z.Kosanovic Yes, it still gives me stuff that's no longer in the code base (i.e. stuff that's only the remote repo)

Comment: at go.mod file add at the end of the file

`replace github.com/garrettlove8/goserve =>../goworkspace/src/github.com/garrettlove8/goserve`

this will replace everytime you want to use goserve to use it by the local path

Comment: @minion Doesn't work, gives error: `goserve/go.mod: no such file or directory
: packages.Load error`

Comment: @Z.Kosanovic Your first suggestion with replace did the trick so if you wanna add that as the answer I'll accept it. The problem was with VS Code not getting the update. I tried with GoLand and it works. If anyone is using VS Code you have to reopen the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use a local module instead of a remote one, you can achieve that with the [replace directive](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace).

In your case, add this to your `go.mod` file:

```
replace github.com/garrettlove8/goserve => ../goworkspace/src/github.com/garrettlove8/goserve
```