# Importing not yet pushed file

Tags: go, dependency-management, go-modules

Hello I have a module `module github.com/foo/bar`.

There is the following structure:

```
project/
    go.mod
    lib.go
    lib_test.go
    folder/
        subfolder/
            requires_lib.go
            requires_lib_test.go
```

and the file `requires_lib.go` has the following header:

```
package subfolder

import "github.com/foo/bar/lib"
```

but the file `github.com/foo/bar/lib/` is not yet pushed, because its a prototype

When launching tests, it tries to resolve that dependency and obviously fails.

Do I have to update the master branch whenever I want to make a change in this file? Even if its present in the file system and I want to actually use the one in the filesystem

Is there any alternative?

Take into account that is another **package** in the same *module* what I want to import.

Thanks.

Comment: the closest i could find is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64295033/import-local-package-thats-already-in-public-repo

Comment: se also https://thewebivore.com/using-replace-in-go-mod-to-point-to-your-local-module/

Comment: Its the same module but a different package.

Comment: Code from the current module is _never_ fetched from the network. There  si nothing to do and nothing to worry about. Just try it out. It works.

Comment: I've tried `module github.com/foo/bar replace github.com/foo/bar => ./ ` in `go.mod` but i can't make it work.

Comment: someting is wrong in your description. In the file graph you have shared, there is only one module.

Comment: `Take into account that is another package in the same module what I want to import.` then there is nothing to download

Comment: Adding a replace directive for the current module is wrong.